# Create a new column in a dataframe by conditional matching in dataframe to a "lookup" dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataframe one

```
gene_symbols<- c ('ABL1', 'ABL1', 'Abl2', 'Accn1', 'Accn1')
Result_value<- c (1, 4, 5, 5, 2)
df<-data.frame(gene_symbols, Result_value)
```

[image]

There are repeats within this dataframe of gene_symbols but it is a mixture of both human and mouse genes.

I also have a second dataframe to be used as a conditional lookup or dictionary

```
humanGene<-c('ABL1', 'ABL2', 'ACCN1')
mouseGene<-c('Abl1', 'Abl2', 'Accn1')
df2<-data.frame(humanGene, mouseGene)
```

[image]

I would like to create a new column in dataframe one of only human genes.  If there is an human gene in column1 it is kept, if there is a mouse gene then it is replaced by the human gene from the df2.  The output should look like:

[image]

I am trying to use a conditional look up

```
df$HumanGene <- ifelse(df$gene.symbols %in% df2$mouseGene, df2$humanGene, df$gene.symbols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a join and `coalesce` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('gene_symbols' = 'mouseGene')) %>%
  mutate(humanGene = coalesce(humanGene, gene_symbols))

#  gene_symbols Result_value humanGene
#1         ABL1            1      ABL1
#2         ABL1            4      ABL1
#3         Abl2            5      ABL2
#4        Accn1            5     ACCN1
#5        Accn1            2     ACCN1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fcoalesce`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df2, humanGene := fcoalesce(humanGene, gene_symbols), on = .(gene_symbols = mouseGene)]
```